# Limit replacement times

Tags: php, regex

is there a function in PHP that I can use to replace a specific character with another one, but I should be able to limit the number of replacements done?
I am currently trying to get preg_replace() to work, as it has that ability, but there seems to be something wrong. Here is what I am using:

```
$args[0] = preg_replace("/\$/", $args[$x], $args[0], 1);

$args[0] contains letters and special "$" characters, which should be replaced.
```

Any help?

Comment: can you post the values of `$args[$x]` and `$args[0]` as example ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried `"/\\$/"` (2 backslashes)?

(See [How to escape $ in PHP using preg_replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767714/how-to-escape-in-php-using-preg-replace/2886788#2886788) for more info)

Answer (score -1):

This is the syntax of replacement fn:

```
preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

so you have to put first the patterns after that the replacements (the char you want to replace with it) at the end of your string.

Comment: And the fourth argument (which is optional) specifies a limit to the number of times the replacement is performed. Thanks for your willingness to post, but it appears that the function's usage is already understood.