# str_replace() with a full web page as the subject

Tags: php, html, replace, str-replace

I'm trying to use `str_replace()` to search and replace specific strings in html pages. For example, I am replacing:

```
$search_string = 'The new&nbsp;funding follows a <a href="http://blog.classpass.com/2015/01/15/were-so-excited-to-share-our-biggest-news-ever/">$40 million raise announced</a> in January.';
```

with

```
$replacement = '<span class="newString">The new&nbsp;funding follows a <a href="http://blog.classpass.com/2015/01/15/were-so-excited-to-share-our-biggest-news-ever/">$40 million raise announced</a> in January.</span>';

$subject = file_get_contents("some-web-site.html");

$new_string = str_replace($search_string, $replacement, $subject);
```

However, the replacement doesn't work, when `$subject` contains a lot of html. If i just do:

```
$subject = "some text some text " .  $search_string . "some text some text";
```

the sentence is correctly replaced. The issue seems to arise specifically due to the `&nbsp;` element.. if the `$search_string` does not contain `&nbsp;` then it will be replaced successfully no matter the complexity of the `$subject` element (i.e. even if it contains a full web page).

Any idea why is that ?

Comment: Are you using `preg_replace` or `str_replace`? You mention both. Doing `str_replace` with something like `"&nbsp;"` seems to work fine for me. `preg_replace` could be failing because it's coming across unescaped metacharacters, e.g. `&`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am using str_replace everywhere. But I would use preg_replace if it can solve the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx with preg\_match to find and replace a SIMILAR string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33671497/regex-with-preg-match-to-find-and-replace-a-similar-string)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with the `$40` part of `$search_string`, not the `&nbsp;`.

Take this program for example:

```
<?php

$input = '$40 &nbsp; replace failed'; // string literal

$str_replace_result = str_replace('$40 &nbsp; replace failed', 'str_replace worked', $input);
print_r($str_replace_result . "\n"); // ==> works

$preg_replace_result = preg_replace('/$40 &nbsp; replaced failed/', 'preg_replace worked', $input);
print_r($preg_replace_result . "\n"); // ==> fails

// Example without the "$40"
$another_string = '&nbsp; replace 2 failed';
$preg_replace_result2= preg_replace('/&nbsp; replace 2 failed/', 'preg_replace worked', $another_string);
print_r($preg_replace_result2. "\n"); // ==> works, implying the "$40" bit was the issue
```

To fix this issue use [`preg_quote`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php), e.g.:

```
// Solution
$escaped_search = preg_quote('/$40 &nbsp; replace failed/');
$newnewstr = preg_replace($escaped_search, 'preg_replace worked', $input);
print_r($newnewstr . "\n"); // ==> works
```

More info in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/767714/4009370).

In conclusion, the issue was that unescaped metacharacters caused the matching to fail.

All that said, is it required that you replace the entirety of the web page in this way? This approach (as is apparent here) seems to be error prone.

Comment: Thanks but I dont think it's related to the dollar sign. If I create a small $subject = "some text". $search_string/*(this contains $40)*/ . "athoer text") it works

Comment: I just need to replace that string inside the web page, not the whole page

Comment: @user3857924 alright. Only other thing I could think of is using smart strings (`"`) vs string literals (`'`), where you want to be using the latter here due to the nature of pattern matching (this still relates back to the `"$"` issue). Other than that, if `preg_quote` doesn't fix your issue, I'm not sure, at least based on the given information.